# How to merge duplicate columns with `.1` into single column without the `.1`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
col1  col1.
1     nan
2     nan
```

How can I merge these columns into one without the .1?

```
col1
1
2
```

I can do this if the column names are the same:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).first()
```

If I try to do string replace, column names get characters removed, not sure why:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.1','')
```

Comment: In your question you talk about a `.1`, but in your sample you only have a period following.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to normalize your columns:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'(\w+)\.?', expand=False)
```

Use `groupby` + `first`:

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

```
   col1
0   1.0
1   2.0
```

---

You can also `groupby` the `regex` result:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract(r'(\w+)\.?', expand=False), axis=1).first()
```